# ASP.NET Core API Swagger - No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44358

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core-5 Web API, I have:

```
public static class AuthExtension
{

    public static void AddJwtAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DDMDbContext>();

        //services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, ApplicationRole>()
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 2;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // ===== Add Jwt Authentication ========
        // Adding Authentication  
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })

        // Adding Jwt Bearer  
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                ValidIssuer = configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
            };
        });
    }
}


public static class WebExtension
{
    public static void AddMvcCoreFramework(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest)
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                {
                    NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
                };
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            });
    }
}

    public static IServiceCollection AddVersioning(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApiVersioning(
            options =>
            {
                // reporting api versions will return the headers "api-supported-versions" and "api-deprecated-versions"
                options.ReportApiVersions = true;
            });
        services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(
            options =>
            {
                // add the versioned api explorer, which also adds IApiVersionDescriptionProvider service
                // note: the specified format code will format the version as "'v'major[.minor][-status]"
                options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";

                // note: this option is only necessary when versioning by url segment. the SubstitutionFormat
                // can also be used to control the format of the API version in route templates
                options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
            });

        return services;
    }


    public static IServiceCollection AddSwagger(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.OperationFilter<SwaggerDefaultValues>();

            options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Scheme = "Bearer",
                Description = "Enter 'Bearer' following by space and JWT Token.",
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http
            });

            options.OperationFilter<SwaggerAuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>();

            // integrate xml comments
            options.IncludeXmlComments(XmlCommentsFilePath);
        });

        return services;
    }
```

appsettings.json:

```
"JWT": {
  "ValidAudience": "http://localhost:4200",
  "ValidIssuer": "http://localhost:44358",
  "Secret": "kkkkkSS1234"
}
```

launchSettings.json:

```
{
 "iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:38845",
    "sslPort": 44358
  }
},
"profiles": {
  "IIS Express": {
    "commandName": "IISExpress",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  },
  "DDM.API.Web": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

This is the startup class for the We API where I called the Extensions

startup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDb(Configuration);
        services.AddJwtAuthentication(Configuration);
        services.AddMvcCoreFramework(Configuration);
        services.AddVersioning();
        services.AddSwagger();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

I got this error:

> This localhost page can’t be found

> No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44358/

How do I get this error sorted out?

Thanks

Comment: In your `launchSettings` you're telling Kestrel (the web server) to bind to `https://localhost:5001` and `http://localhost:5000`, but in your `appsettings` you're saying that the valid issuer is `http://localhost:44358`, change the value either in `launchSettings` or `appsettings` to the same URL

Comment: @MindSwipe maybe he's not using Kestrel, but indeed using IIS... but the configuration's a mess yeah.

Comment: @MindSwipe - I'm using IIS. When I did this in launcgSettings: "sslPort": 5001,    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",  and in appsettings:   "ValidIssuer": "http://localhost:5001",.  I got this error:   Hmmm… can't reach this page

Comment: Hi @Olugbenga, that is because you do not specific the controller default value. Just specific the value like : `pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");`. Also be sure add `services.AddControllersWithViews()`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, it will show a 404 page because the Swagger UI page is not configured as the default page. Try accessing `/swagger` you will get the swagger UI page. Or you can modify the code like this.

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });
}
```

Now it will show the swagger page as the default one.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add  AddControllers() to services, something like this

```
  services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
```

and fix  a default route

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

Comment: That's part of the code. I've updated my post with the whole code. The error is still there. Check my updated code for everything

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it adding the following settings at the lauchsettings.json just below the launchBrowser key/value

```
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
```